# Forwarding incoming ports to another private IP on my existing setup, IPTABLES

Tags: debian, iptables, port-forwarding, gateway

On my Debian 8 gateway:
I want to forward incoming port 9000 to 192.168.4.10:3389 and incoming 9001 port to 192.168.4.11:3389.

`DHCP - WAN - eth0 -----> eth2 - LAN - 192.168.4.1`

I am using rules.v4 below with iptables-restore. I don't have that much experience with iptables and all the tutorials on the web I couldn't implement this to my existing rules.

I am using Debian 8 with iptables v1.4.21

My existing iptables rules below.

```
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.21 on Sat Jul 25 12:31:07 2020
*nat
-A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
COMMIT

*filter
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
# allow ssh, so that we do not lock ourselves
# allow ping from WAN side
--append INPUT --protocol icmp --icmp-type any --src [REDACTED_IP] --jump ACCEPT


# open ports for gateway services
-A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i eth2 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i bond0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT

-A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 9091 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i eth2 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 9091 -j ACCEPT

-A INPUT -i bond0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8200 -j ACCEPT

-A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

-A INPUT -i eth0 -j DROP

COMMIT
```

I am restoring these rules with
`iptables-restore < /etc/iptables/rules.v4`

Any help will be highly appreciated.Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Provided the gateway has two NICs (`eth0` is WAN facing while `eth2` is LAN facing).
First rule will enable packet forwarding (aka routing). Incoming traffic from internet will hit `eth0`, then translated to remote destination host by rules #2 and #3.  This is known as Destination NAT ([DNAT](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/4/html/security_guide/s1-firewall-ipt-fwd)). Fourth rule enables NAT (masquerade).

```
$ sudo echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
$ sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -i eth0 --dport 9000 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.4.10:3389
$ sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -i eth0 --dport 9001 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.4.11:3389
$ sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -j MASQUERADE
```

Then consider permanent changes if all goes well.